# Endless Loop Problem with foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach, exec, infinite-loop

Ok, i have a `ENDLESS LOOP` i need that loop endless nothing wrong with it! When i start that script via `php script.php` it works no problem, but on the second thrid and so on...run it dont works any more proper. I added as test the $output on the second run into the DB to see whats wrong and im getting this error `a:1:{i:0;s:24:"sh: 0: command not found";}` its serialized.

Remember the script works on the first run, but never on the 2nd+ run, something is wrong with $output and $video on the 2nd 3rd+ run,

Encoding works in every run also the files get proper renamed, and moved proper

I tried to unset `$output` `$video` `$duration` and `$error` at the end of the script, but than i get a error, variables not defined on the 2nd+ run. Any ideas whats wrong?

About the code: I put a snippet not the full code, if typos in there its only copypaste error.

My thinking is something with `exec` is wrong, when they give the output to the variable on the 2nd+ run

Here is my script

```
<?php


while(10) {
    // Getting Data From DB
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos_to_edit WHERE status = 'pending' ORDER BY post_time ASC LIMIT 1";

    // Encoding Video;
    exec("$mencoder $temp_upload_dir$post_filename -o  $temp_upload_dir$r_post_id.mp4 2>&1", $output);

    // Checking if Mencoder could encode it
    foreach($output as $error) {

        if(preg_match('/============ Sorry, this file format is not recognized\/supported =============/', $error)) {

            $error1 = "error";

        }

    }
    if(!isset($error1)) {

        // Getting duration of Video with mplayer
        exec("$mplayer $temp_upload_dir$r_post_id.mp4 2>&1", $video);
        // Getting the duration with preg_match
        foreach($video as $vidlenght) {

            if(preg_match('/ID_LENGTH=/', $vidlenght)) {
                $duration = $vidlenght;
                $duration = explode("=",$duration);
                $duration = $duration['1'];

            }

        }


        // MOVING FILE TO PUBLIC DIR
        CODE HERE...

        //UPDATING DB
        $sql = "UPDATE videos_to_edit SET status = 'finished' WHERE post_id = ?";

    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: Why do you use `while(10)`? That condition is always true.

Comment: cause i want a endless loop please read the text above

Answer (score 2):

Could it be because you never reset `$error1`? If it's ever set here:

```
$error1 = "error";
```

it remains set.

Comment: hi, i sorry was not in the code above, $error gets also reset at the end of the script.

Comment: Your code picks a pending video, tries to encode it, if that fails it sets $error1, then loops around. I can't see where you're resetting $error1 before picking the next video. Actually, it looks like the code doesn't modify the database if encoding fails, so next time it picks the _same_ pending video, tries to encode it again, etc.